# Does anyone know the package name of the factory reset option for Samsung phones on 6.0+

Tags: android, shell

I used this adb command line: pm disable 'com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings' using the android root shell but of course it disables all sub settings and not just the reset option. Would it be possible to disable only the factory reset option?

Comment: Try this one "com.android.settings/.MasterClear". Why didn't you want to disable factory reset via DPM or Knox Standard SDK?

Comment: Thanks mate, tried the command but .MasterClear isnt apart of com.android.setting. DPM  would do the trick however I need to do some reading on this. We are currently seeing an in house android dev, Is it okay to post contact details here?